# Auto flying mouse on my laptop

Tags: keyboard, mouse-cursor, bug.n

In my laptop a problem is occuring that mouse cursor is automatic moving, and  shift key is pressed hence there is no problem in keyboard. 
So I tried to solve these problems but I haven't found any solution.
I uninstalled mouse and keyboard driver s but it didn't repair.
I didn't found any viruses in laptop.
Oh remember I am not connected with wifi also.
So can you help me?

Comment: Does your keyboard have a [touchpoint nub like this?](https://hackernoon.com/hn-images/1*3N40PFWaiE30Vavum_V3fQ.png)

Comment: `Oh remember I am not connected with wifi also` Is that somehow related with the mouse issue or is it another problem?

Comment: @udlp no, my keyboard doesn't have touchpoint nub

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio , I think this issue is related to mouse because this problem is occuring when I am trying to format my laptop by windows software.

Comment: What software? What drive are you formatting? Why do you think it's related to your mouse?

Comment: Because this problem occuring during system formatting, and it's the reason why I think that this problem is cause of hardware. If this was problem of software it can't happen during system formatting.